# Error in stri_detect_regex in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, text, error-handling

I am receiving this error

> Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
>     Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)

when I run the code

```
  # find occurrences of initial dataframe
  named_RN$search <- map_int(named_RN$V1, function(x){sum(str_detect(final_RN$named_RN, pattern = x))})
```

in which `named_RN$V1` looks like

```
aldosterone
renin
potassium
calcitrol
```

and `final_RN$named_RN` looks like

```
aldosterone, creatinine 
human, warfarin
aspirin, renin, calcitrol
magnesium, calcitrol
```

and my code aims to create a new variable within `named_RN` that shows the raw counts of each phrase, so that `named_RN` looks like

```
V1              search
aldosterone     1
renin           0
potassium       0
calcitrol       2
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: You got incorrectly nested parentheses in one of the regular expression patterns. Check out e.g. `stringr::str_detect(c("a","a("), c("a", "a("))` versus  `stringr::str_detect(c("a","a("), stringr::fixed(c("a", "a(")))`. Maybe get rid of the parentheses or use fixed matching?

Comment: If you match using fixed strings, not regex, you really just need to use `str_detect(final_RN$named_RN, fixed(x))`

Comment: @Wiktor, that worked! mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using fixed strings, not regular expressions, you need to tell the regex engine to use the patterns as plain, literal text. You can use it like this:

```
str_detect(final_RN$named_RN, fixed(x))
                              ^^^^^^^^
```

See [*"Fixed matches"*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html#fixed-matches):

> `fixed(x)` only matches the exact sequence of bytes specified by `x`. This is a very limited “pattern”, but the restriction can make matching much faster.

You might also consider `coll(x)` in case you want to use human-language collation rules while performing a case insensitive search.