# Matching across two columns using str_detect in dplyr()

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I am trying to match across two columns in `mydata` to create a new column called `match`. I first want to remove any rows that have 'none' in either `Word1` or `Word2`:

```
 Token     Word1     Word2
 1         cat       cat
 2         dog       cat
 3         hamster   none
 4         sheep     sheep
 5         none      hamster
```

I have used the following code in `dplyr()`:

```
 mydata %>% filter(Word1 != "none" | Word2 != "none") %>%
   mutate(match = str_detect(Word1 , Word2)) %>%
   filter(match == FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

```
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
   Evaluation error: Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. 
 (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN).
```

When I run `mydata %>% filter(Word1 != "none" | Word2 != "none")` only the function works fine, so I can't see how it is an error in my parentheses. But perhaps I'm missing something really obvious here! (I have used `str_detect` successfully plenty of times before!)

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828985/error-in-stri-detect-regex-in-r/45849886#45849886) about using `fixed(x)` but when I applied this to my code with `mutate(match = str_detect(Word1 , Word2), fixed(x))` I get the same error in the output.

Comment: Are you trying to match literal text? Try `str_detect(Word1 , fixed(Word2))`

Comment: `df %>% mutate(match = str_detect(Word1, Word2)) %>% filter(!match)` works fine for me

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perfect! Fixed - thank you!